# Is there a way to cluster leaflet markers with similar properties ?

Tags: maps, leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson, markerclusterer

I create my layers from geoJson, which has specified adress among other things.
I understand that grouping is done based on distance between them and current zoom to map. I want to achieve that markers on one street stay grouped(clustered) even on max zoom and implement layer.spiderify on click (which I have by now). 
I searched pages and examples Im quest for finding the answer for few days and now I turn on stack for a hunt.